# Search Custom Post Type Custom Fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, search

There are tutorials that explain how to limit a search to a specific category.

My question is, is there a way to configure wordpress' search to, within a custom post type, search for a custom field value.

So for example, if I search for "hello", the results would come up with posts that have a certain custom field equal to "hello". The certain post would also be a certain custom post type.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can try building a custom search.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this hidden field to the search form?

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="news" />
```

For value="", you should include the name of your custom post type, of course.